# 2 audios playing at the same time in mediapalyer in android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-mediaplayer

HELP PLEASE !!

I'm using media player in recycler view and the problem is when different item's play buttons are clicked they all play at the same time. How can I stop the previous audio and start the new audio ?

Here is the adapter code:

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder>  {
    final MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();


 public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
        try {
            mediaPlayer.reset();
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(item.get(position).getAudio());
            mediaPlayer.prepare();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

viewHolder.play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                        mediaPlayer.pause();
                        viewHolder.play.setImageResource(R.drawable.play);

                } else {
                    mediaPlayer.start();
                    viewHolder.play.setImageResource(R.drawable.pause);
                }
```

I suppose one answer is using flag. but I don't know how to implement it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple audios that play at the same time because there are multiple instances of the `MediaPlayer` object, because it's instantiated on every call to the `onBindViewHolder()`; i.e. each row of the `RecyclerView` will have a unique object.

To fix this, you need to use only a single object for all the audio, so transfer the

```
final MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
```

To be a direct field to the adapter class.

UPDATE:

Now change the logic of play button click

```
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {

    viewHolder.play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
            
                if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                    mediaPlayer.stop();
                    mediaPlayer.release();
                    viewHolder.play.setImageResource(R.drawable.play);
                } 
                
                try {
                    mediaPlayer.reset();
mediaPlayer.setDataSource(item.get(position).getAudio());
                    mediaPlayer.prepare();
                    mediaPlayer.start();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                
                viewHolder.play.setImageResource(R.drawable.pause);
                            
            }
        }

}
```

UPDATE 2:

Try to transfer the play button code to the ViewHolder instead of the `onBindViewHolder`, and instead of the `position`, use [`getAbsoluteAdapterPosition()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.ViewHolder#getAbsoluteAdapterPosition())

```
public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    //.....
    
    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        play = itemView.findViewById(...);
        
        play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
            
                // ..... Add the mediaPlayer code
                                
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I transferred it to the beginning of code and now I'm getting errors in the setDataSource  line

Comment: Can you update the question with the error you got.. Full stacktrace please

Comment: @ghazalia Please add `mediaPlayer.reset()` just before  `mediaPlayer.setDataSource()`

Comment: now I don't have error. but still when I click two play buttons both audios play together

Comment: @ghazalia Please have look at the updated answer

Comment: it didn't work. the problem is still there

Comment: did you find any answers?

Comment: @ghazalia Please have a look at `UPDATE 2`

Comment: how should I say this?             `mediaPlayer.setDataSource(getAbsoluteAdapterPosition().getAudio());`      now it doesn't resolve symbol getAbsolute

Comment: Can you show me how you initialize the `item` in `onBindViewHolder`.. I mean `item = ...`

Comment: `public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
        viewHolder.App.setText(item.get(position).getApp());`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236800/discussion-between-zain-and-ghazalia).

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem of double instantiation of MediaPlayer() class. What you have to do is to make an object class like this:

```
import android.media.MediaPlayer
import android.net.Uri
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService
import java.util.concurrent.Executors

object MusicObject {

    private lateinit var mediaPlayer: MediaPlayer
    private val executor: ExecutorService = Executors.newCachedThreadPool()
    private var flag = 0
    private var musicName = ""
    private var musicID = 1
    private var musicUri: Uri? = null

    // Function to play music
    fun playMusic(mp: MediaPlayer,name: String,ID: Int,Uri: Uri) {
        if (flag > 0) {
            pauseMusic()
        }
        flag++
        musicName = name
        musicID = ID
        musicUri = Uri
        mediaPlayer = mp
        executor.execute {
            mediaPlayer.start()
        }
    }

    // Function to play currently playing music again
    fun playMusicAgain() {
        executor.execute {
            mediaPlayer.start()
        }
    }

    // Function to pause music
    fun pauseMusic() {
        mediaPlayer.pause()
    }

    // Function to stop music
    fun stopMusic() {
        if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying) {
            mediaPlayer.stop()
        }
    }

    fun getMediaPlayer(): MediaPlayer {
        return mediaPlayer
    }
}
```

And call this class to play and pause the music.

To play music:

```
MusicObject.playMusic(MediaPlayer.create(this, songUri), idOfMusic, songID, songUri)
```

To pause music:

```
MusicObject.pauseMusic()
```